# Dynamically changing select options with jquery

Tags: jquery, joomla, html-select

I have a question about select options. Is it possible with jquery to change select options with respect to another selected option? In my case, I have a t-shirt product and I have let say colour and size characteristics. And I do not have for every colour the same size options. So is it possible to change the size options when the client selects the colour option with jquery. 
More details: 
I have an e-shop using joomla extension hikashop. In the backend of the hikashop I can set multiple chracteristics (options) for each product. Then let say one characteristic (color) for a given product appears in HTML as below

```
 <select id="hikashop_product_characteristic_5" name="hikashop_product_characteristic[5]"
    class="inputbox" size="1" onchange="return hikashopUpdateVariant(this);">
    <option value="29">Blue</option>
    <option value="11" selected="selected">White</option>
    <option value="12">Red</option>
    </select>
```

Then the second characteristic (size) appears under as below;

```
<select id="hikashop_product_characteristic_21" name="hikashop_product_characteristic[21]"      
class="inputbox" size="1" onchange="return hikashopUpdateVariant(this);">
<option value="18" selected="selected">M</option>
<option value="19">L</option>
<option value="17">S</option>
<option value="20">XL</option>
</select>
```

Note: I have contacted the customer service of the hikashop and the response was it would be very complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the options directly, but a much simpler solution is to use a plugin like [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/).

Then it could be as simple as:

```
$('#inputbox').select2({"data": optionArray});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add some attributes to *options*?

If yes, you can deal with the problem in different way:

```
 <select id="hikashop_product_characteristic_5" name="hikashop_product_characteristic[5]"
class="inputbox" size="1">
    <option value="29" data-sizes="18,19">Blue</option>
    <option value="11" selected="selected">White</option>
    <option value="12" data-sizes="18">Red</option>
</select>

<select id="hikashop_product_characteristic_21" name="hikashop_product_characteristic[21]" class="inputbox" size="1">
    <option value="18" selected="selected">M</option>
    <option value="19">L</option>
    <option value="17">S</option>
    <option value="20">XL</option>
</select>
```

So javascript will be look like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hikashop_product_characteristic_5").on("change", function(){
        var sizesToEnable = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("data-sizes").split(","),
          i = 0,
          value;

        $("#hikashop_product_characteristic_21 option").each(function(){
           value = $(this).val();
           if($.inArray(value, sizesToEnable) === true) {
               $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
               continue;
           }
           $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for spending time to find a solution. I am not able to change much on hikashop product therefore I could not implement what you have posted.